# How to get Dictionaries out of [SFQuerySpec newSmartQuerySpec:]

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

When i fire a smart query in iOS as shown below on a Contacts soup -

```
NSString* const kContactsQuery = @"SELECT {Contacts:uid},{Contacts:firstName}, {Contacts:lastName}, {Contacts:phonenumber} FROM {Contacts}";

 [SFQuerySpec newSmartQuerySpec:kContactsQuery withPageSize:10]
```

i get data as array of array's ->

```
(
        (
        1,
        Sandeep,
        Kandula,
        12345678
    ),
        (
        2,
        Sandeep11,
        Kandula112,
        123456
    ),
        (
        2,
        Sandeep2,
        Kandula2,
        123456782
    ),

)
```

Is there a way to get the result in Array of Dictionaries. Like shown below ->

```
(
        {
        "uid":"1",
        "firstname":"Sandeep",
        "lastname":"Kandula",
        "pnumber":"12345678"
    }
)
```

Please point me in correct direction. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can someone please help me by answering the Q.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the SmartSyncExplorer app, the SObjectDataManager class calls populateDataRows after the query. If you follow a similar approach, I think the best route today would to be to create an additional method that takes in an array of field names similar to this (written in Swift):

```
func populateDataRows(queryResults: [AnyObject], fields: [String]) -> [SObjectData] {
    var mutableDataRows: [SObjectData] = []
    for result in queryResults {
        var resultDict: [String: AnyObject] = [:]
        for var i:Int = 0; i < fields.count; i++ {
            resultDict[fields[i]] = result[i]
        }
        mutableDataRows.append(self.dataSpec.createSObjectData(resultDict))
    }

    return mutableDataRows
}
```

I would conditionally call this depending on whether you're using a SmartQuery or not.